# DatePickerFor does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker, telerik

I am using telerik DatePickerFor for getting datetime value. Here is my model class:

```
  public class Kisi
{

    [Display(Name="date1")]
    public DateTime date1{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "date2")]
    public DateTime date2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "date3")]
    public DateTime date3{ get; set; }

}
```

Here is my view class:

```
//most parts ommited for brevity
@model LojmanMVC.Domain.Kisi

@{
ViewBag.Title = "KisiOlustur2";
}


<h2>KisiOlustur2</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>

    <!-- date1-->
    <div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label>date1? </label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">


            @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m=>m.date1)
            .Name("dtpickerMemuriyetBaslama")
            .Min(new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
            .Max(new DateTime(2099, 12, 31))
            .Value(DateTime.Today)

             )

            <br />

            <!-- Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemuriyetBaslamaTarihi)-->
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="tey" style="display:none">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m=>m.date2)
            .Name("dtAskerlikBaslama")
            .Min(new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
            .Max(new DateTime(2099, 12, 31))
            .Value(DateTime.Today)

            )


            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AskerlikBaslangicTarihi)
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="hey" style="display:none">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date3)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m=>m.AskerlikBitisTarihi)
            .Name("dtAskerlikBitis")
            .Min(new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
            .Max(new DateTime(2099, 12, 31))
            .Value(DateTime.Today)

            )

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Oluştur" />
    </p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my controller :

```
    public class KisiController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Kisi/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult KisiOlustur2()
    {



        Kisi kisi = new Kisi();
        return View(kisi);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult KisiOlustur2(Kisi sisi)
    {


        return View(sisi);
    }


}
```

at sisi variable, date1,date2 and date3 is null, even though I entered them. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have overridden the `name` attribute so it will not bind to your model. Remove the `.Name("....")` code from each datepicker

Comment: thank you Mr Stephen Muecke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, one thing I would suggest adding to your model, is the following:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date.")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name="date1")]
public DateTime date1{ get; set; }
```

You can customise the format string how you like and also your error message. This will ensure what the user enters has to actually be a date in the correct format.

However, I think your issue is that you are not actually passing the date from the view to the controller, you need to give your DatePickerFor a name and then pass this name into the controller for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KisiOlustur2(Kisi sisi, DateTime dtAskerlikBitis)
{
    return View(sisi);
}
```

Comment: I do not need to pass DateTime as a parameter, KisiOlustur2 functioning well. Thank you.